# Unable to format or wipe an external HDD

Tags: external-hdd

A friend asked me to wipe/format a 2TB external HDD. It just doesn't work.

With `lsblk -l` I can see the disk which is formatted in NTFS and mounted as /dev/sdg1.

I tried `mkfs.fat /dev/sdg1`, resulting in `mkfs.fat: /dev/sdg1 contains a mounted filesystem.`

`sudo umount /dev/sdg` just takes forever and nothing happens.

Then I tried `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg1 bs=1M`, but again, nothing happens. No output; all I can do is close the terminal window and terminate the process.

Finally I entered `sudo gparted`. The program keeps loading until I plug out the external HDD, only then it shows my computer's SSD.

I've never had this problem with any hard drive before. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at it's health, ie. using the drive's SMART technology.  Is the drive healthy?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Apparently it doesn't support SMART. All I get is:
`/dev/sdg: Unknown USB bridge [0x0bc2:0xab26 (0x108)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.`

Answer (score 1):

You must `sudo umount /dev/sdg1` before you can change the disk's structure.

While the disk (or any partition) is mounted, the disk structure exists in two places: On the disk; and in kernel memory.

While the disk is NOT mounted, the structure information exists only on the disk.

A simple user program (`gparted`), even if running as `root` shoud NOT manipulate the disk structure in kernel memory. It doesn't know how (for every OS/kernel/filesystem version), there are synchronizations issues, etc.

Therefore, the `umount /dev/sdg1` is required *before* you attack the disk with `gparted`.

`